# show list of div as table

Tags: html

I have a list of divs, with diffrent not fixed height, and I wnat to show them as table.

Example of div list

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="item">1 some some some text1</div>
   <div class="item">2 a few text2</div>
   <div class="item">3 a lotttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttt of text3</div>
   <div class="item">4some text</div>
   <div class="item">5 some text</div>
   <div class="item">6 some text</div>
<div>
```

and I want to see it some thing like this:
[link text](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/image.php?c8ca4af08e.png)

Comment: Are your divs being created or populated dynamically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend using three column `div`s with `float: left` and a fixed width (e.g. `30%` and a `3%` margin to make the gap).

- Column 1 contains containers 1 and 4
- Column 2 contains containers 2 and 6
- Column 3 contains containers 3 and 5

In those `div`s, you would then have the actual boxes with their varying heights. You would make borders with `border: 5px black solid`; the gap to the box below would be a `margin-bottom:  5px` for exampke.

Comment: I'm understand you but, I can't manege order of divs in list. each of div must select top position in smallest column.